# PHP-OpenCloud with OpenStack installed Locally

Tags: 12.04, openstack

I have a question that can we use `PHP-OpenCloud` for building applications for `OpenStack` that is installed locally on a single machine running all services?

I have a doubt that that is only for `RackSpace`? Tell me I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work with Private openstack as well but you'll want to call `use OpenCloud\OpenStack;` rather than `use OpenCloud\Rackspace;`